# DotNetNuke Page Redirecting

Tags: dotnetnuke, redirect

When I browsing my DotNetNuke application from the server, it automatically redirects to error.aspx.

How do I cause my DotNetNuke application to serve default.aspx when visited from the server?

Answer (score 0):

Raghu, I don't think that the problem is the default page.  The problem is that there is an error with your installation.

Check the event log: Admin \ Event Viewer.  I'm guessing you'll find errors there.

You have many dotnetnuke questions that are much better handled on the [dotnetnuke forum](http://www.dotnetnuke.com/tabid/795/default.aspx), it is very actively managed, and there you will find many people who can help you get started with dotnetnuke.